# Alternative to Theia?

Tags: theia

With the [Theia Framework](https://github.com/theia-ide/theia) providing the possibility of building up a JavaScript-based IDE being able to run in any modern browser, I wonder if there are alternative products / frameworks available.

Are there existing frameworks providing the same or similar functionality as Theia? Or is this currently the only one?

Comment: We searched for alternatives before starting the project and couldn't find something that would fit our needs. Which is why we started Theia.

Comment: Yes I agree with Sven.. There is no other alternative.. And I feel Theia is a really good framework to develop IDEs in browser.

Comment: This question is off topic here, but would en on topic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ***if asked correctly***. Just asking for an alternative is no t helpful - try emacs. Instead, please ask us there and give us requirements. The more detail you provide, the better the reply you might get (GIGO).

Comment: @SvenEfftinge I have D/Led Tehia - how do I get running as a desktop app? If the info is available, it is well hidden ;-)

Comment: I was about to write an answer tagging `gitpod.io`, but while google searching to figure out when it was launched I came to discover that it is not really an alternative but rather another solution based on Eclipse Theia, just like Red Hat's CodeReady Workspaces is.

It also looks to me like GitPod's founder commented on this question earlier...  :)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I'm late but it probably answers your question: https://theia-ide.org/docs/blueprint_download#downloads Keep in mind that it's a blueprint.

Comment: Thanks, and upvote. "Eclipse Theia Blueprint is not a production-ready product. Therefore, it is also not meant to be a replacement for Visual Studio Code or any other IDE", but I will certainly be keeping an eye on the project. Thanks for reminding us of it